# gRPC onClose vs onCancel

Tags: grpc-java

Assume that I have a service with something along the lines of

```
service EventService {
  rpc Subscribe (stream Subscription) returns (stream Event) {}
}
```

where we multiplex events for different subscriptions over the same channel. I then have the handler:

```
public StreamObserver<Subscription> subscribe(StreamObserver<Event> responseObserver) {
    ((ServerCallStreamObserver) responseObserver).setOnCloseHandler(() -> /* something */);
    return new StreamObserver<Subscription>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Subscription value) { /* something */ }
    
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) { /* something */ }
    
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() { /* something */ }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() { /* something */ }
    };
}
```

First the docs are unclear on whether the `onCancel()` callback is necessary or if `onComplete()` or `onError()` are always guaranteed to be called. On both cancel and error I basically need to just tear down the resources, so is there any reason to implement both?

Second on the responseObserver, what will be the difference between `setOnCloseHandler()` and `setOnCancelHandler()`? Is there a case where one, but not the other would be called?

What I mostly care about is what happens in any of the following cases:

1. Client closes due to missed keepalive
2. Server closes due to missed keepalive
3. Underlying TCP socket dies or OS signals an error

Which handlers are called on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at the example: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/ccf91018285cf112c0cc287cd9f1ef6ad161717e/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/cancellation/CancellationServer.java#L102

If by the time of cancellation `onCompleted()` hasn't been called, then `onCancel()` and `onError()` are both called, otherwise just `onCancel()` is called.

So the `onError()` is not guaranteed to be called with `onCancel()` and you need to implement both.

BTW, notice how they reuse `onCancel()` for the `setOnCancelHandler` on this line: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/ccf91018285cf112c0cc287cd9f1ef6ad161717e/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/cancellation/CancellationServer.java#L154

> Second on the responseObserver, what will be the difference between setOnCloseHandler() and setOnCancelHandler()? Is there a case where one, but not the other would be called?

`setOnCloseHandler(Runnable onCloseHandler)` will set the handler that will "be executed when the call is closed cleanly from the server's point of view: either `onCompleted()` or `onError(Throwable)` has been called, all the messages and trailing metadata have been sent and the stream has been closed."

`setOnCancelHandler(Runnable onCancelHandler)` will set the handler that will "be called if the call is cancelled and the server is encouraged to
abort processing to save resources, since the client will not process any further messages. Cancellations can be caused by timeouts, explicit cancellation by the client, network errors, etc."

So in the cases you mention the `onCancelHandler` will be called.

"Exactly one of `onCloseHandler` and `onCancelHandler` is guaranteed to be called when the RPC terminates." -- so it is always one or another.